# Send data url with jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have a problem sending data with spaces using load in jquery. Example below.

```javascript
<script>
function load_locations (tipo_send,value_sel) { 
    jQuery("#location").load("modulos/mod_register/index_register.php?send_location=ok&tipo_send="+tipo_send+"&data_loc="+value_sel+"&city_post="+city_post);
}
</script>
```

```php
<?php
print "<select name='reg[pais]' id='sel_1_country' class='register_input_text' onchange=\"load_locations('region',this.value);\">";
print "<option value='reinicio' onclick=\"load_locations('reinicio',this.value);\">Seleccionar País</option>";
print "<option>London City</option></select>";
?>
```

The script works fine. The problem appears when I use  "London City" with a space. When I use "London-City" without spaces the problem doesn't appear.

I tried `urlencode`, etc but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `"i try all , urlencode"` - I suspect that isn't the case, because URL-encoding the values is exactly how one would handle spaces in query string parameters.

Comment: Yes always the proble it´s when i use names separated by spaces , in this moment the script no works , but if i put something "-" "_" , etc , never fail

Comment: Right, spaces in query string values need to be URL-encoded.  That's how you solve that problem.  If you're having trouble with spaces in the *keys* for your values, you solve *that* problem by not using spaces in the keys.  How exactly is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode your data values:

```
jQuery("#location").load("modulos/mod_register/index_register.php?send_location=ok&tipo_send="+encodeURIComponent(tipo_send)+"&data_loc="+encodeURIComponent(value_sel)+"&city_post="+encodeURIComponent(city_post));
```

When using `jQuery.load()` a `space` is used to separate the `url` and the `fragment` (eg element id) within the document you would like to load as opposed to loading the whole page.